# Domain Controller error after removing legacy SBS server from the local network

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, windows-sbs-2008

I am migrating a `Windows SBS 2008` to a `Windows Server 2016` and thought I was on the last mile, shtting down the source SBS server.

It seems my domain still depends on the legacy SBS though. When I remove the old server from the network (either by shutting it down or just pulling the network cable) I am getting 2 problems:

#### Error when starting the *"Dashboard"* on the target server

```
Windows Server Essentials:
    Networking domain controller server ist not accessible, some operations in Dashboard may not succeed. 
    Please check your network and make sure you can access the domain controller server.
```

#### Error when starting starting *"Active Directory Users & Computers"* on target server

```
Active Directory Domain Services:
    Naming information can not be located because the specified domain  
    either does not exist or could not be contacted.
```

Practically this results into not being able to see any Domain User Accounts once the source server is cut off from the local network. Maybe other stuff running in the background may be affected as well which I am not aware of.

thus far I have removed some entries in the `DNS Manager` on the source server, pointing at itself. But that neither has helped yet, nor does googleing the results return any solutions really.
I still find one entry for the source Server in the target server @ `>Active Directory Users and Computers >[domain] >Domain Controllers`.

Any idea how to get over these 2 issues?

---

**EDIT:**

```
C:\Users\admin>netdom query fsmo   
Schema master           [newserver].[mydomain].local   
Domain naming master    [newserver].[mydomain].local   
PDC                     [newserver].[mydomain].local
RID pool manager        [newserver].[mydomain].local
Infrastructure master   [newserver].[mydomain].local   
The command completed successfully.
```

Moving the fsmo roles over to the [newserver] was a pretty bumpy ride though because nothing worked as lined out in the how-to we where trying to use. But in the end the netdom query output was like posted above (which is how it should be as I understand)

**EDIT 2:**
I got a hint for looking at entries in the target Servers `DNS Manager` and actually get soome references to the source server

- `>Forward-Lookupzones >myDomain>_msdcs` has a Name Server (NS) entry which still refers to the SBS - I guess I change the ip address here, so it points to the new server, right?
- `>Forward-Lookupzones>[myDomain] >/sites >/Default-First-Site-Name >/_tcp` has 2 entries (one for the old, one for the new server) for `_gc`, `_kerbereos` & `_ldap`
- `>Forward-Lookupzones>[myDomain] >/_tcp` has 2 entries (one for the old, one for the new server) for `_gc`, `_kerbereos`, `_ldap` and additionally `_kpasswd`
- similar situation (doublette entries for [oldserver] & [newserver] for `_udp<`& other entries in the DNS Manager  - shall I remove the Versions pointing to the old SBS Server?

**EDIT 3:**

I can **ping** the 2 servers mutually with `ping [hostname].local` (which returns the **IPv6** address, where `ping (hostname)` returns the IPv4 address) but not via `ping [domain].[hostname].local`. If I understand it correctly this is another indicator for the same sort of problems. Does that point to a solution?

**EDIT 4:** @expx

Searching the system log with an equivalent German term, the server acutually returned 3 entries (of which 2 where just confirmations, not errors)

```
Protokollname: System
Quelle: Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy
Datum: 06.07.2018 11:12:48
Ereignis-ID: 1058
Aufgabenkategorie:Keine
Level: Error
keywords:
User: SYSTEM
Computer: [oldserver].[domain].local
Description:

Error while processing the Group policy. The attempt to read the file "\so6.local\SysVol\so6.local\Policies{3474E153-5F07-4EC3-B816-9C0405CCF68F}\gpt.ini" from a Domaincontroller was not successful.
Group policiy settings can't be applied until this event is resolved. This could be a temporay problem which could have at least one of the following causes:
a) name resolution/network connection with the current Domaincontroller
b) Waiting period of the File Replication Service
c) the DFS-Clilent has been deactivated

Event-XML:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy" Guid="{aea1b4fa-97d1-45f2-a64c-4d69fffd92c9}" />
<EventID>1058</EventID>
<Version>0</Version>
<Level>2</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Opcode>1</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-07-06T09:12:48.941Z" />
<EventRecordID>1643448</EventRecordID>
<Correlation ActivityID="{C8828C15-D9E9-4FC6-8DE1-927F01129AB1}" />
<Execution ProcessID="520" ThreadID="1260" />
<Channel>System</Channel>
<Computer>SO6SERVER.so6.local</Computer>
<Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="SupportInfo1">4</Data>
<Data Name="SupportInfo2">840</Data>
<Data Name="ProcessingMode">1</Data>
<Data Name="ProcessingTimeInMilliseconds">3027</Data>
<Data Name="ErrorCode">53</Data>
<Data Name="ErrorDescription">Der Netzwerkpfad wurde nicht gefunden. </Data>
<Data Name="DCName">\SO6SERVER.so6.local</Data>
<Data Name="GPOCNName">cn={3474E153-5F07-4EC3-B816-9C0405CCF68F},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=so6,DC=local</Data>
<Data Name="FilePath">\so6.local\SysVol\so6.local\Policies{3474E153-5F07-4EC3-B816-9C0405CCF68F}\gpt.ini</Data>
</EventData>
</Event>
```

practically I can read the file mentioned when I am accessing (as the Domain admin)

Comment: What is the output of `netdom query fsmo` on the 2016 DC, and are all client using the 2016 DC for DNS?

Comment: adding in the post @GregAskew

Comment: And all Clients have a static IP (IPv4) and use the IP address of the new server in 'preferred DNS Serverver' in the Network Adapter Settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AD is multi-master environment able to determine which DC is alive and which is dead. In general, you should remove all those DNS records in the end but that shouldn't prevent you to use new DC if old DC is simply off network. This seems like some kind of replication issue to me. if you navigate to \\newserver do you see all shares (NETLOGON and SYSVOL)? Also, is old server 2008 or 2008 R2. If it's plain 2008 it may uses FRS instead of DFSR which can cause issues with new versions of DCs (2012 and later). Login to old DC, open Event Viewer and see if you can find any errors pointing to FRS (for instance JOURNAL_WRAP errors).

Comment: thx for the pointers, sounds like a lot of fun ahead of me next week :-)

Comment: if I navigate to \\[newserver] in the filebrowser of a client I can see all folder's which are located in the `Server Folders`directory on the [newserver]. Also 3 shared printers & a folder named "CertEnroll". Anything else I should see (sorry, not sure what exactly `NETLOGON` & `SYSVOL` means even though I've heard the terms before)?

Comment: I can't find any log entries by using the search terms you've mentioned (`FRS` , `JOURNAL_WRAP`, `DFSR`) in the Source Servers Event Viewer (tried in `System`, `Setup`, `Security` & `Applications`)

Comment: when you navigate to \\\newserver you should see NETLOGON and SYSVOL shares there, it's critical for AD environment. can you confirm you can see both shares present? Also, did you search log on old or new server? It should be old one.

Comment: searched the logs in the old server as you said. Can't see any `NETLOGON`, nor `SYSVOL` when browsing to \\newserver. So this (asides the errors mentioned above) then tells me that something IS wrong. Does it point towards a certain solution as well?

Comment: that's definitely issue with replication, i've seen similar issues when moving from older server to 2016. are you completely sure you don't see errors on source domain controller? something like this: https://i.imgur.com/IjVYvFk.jpg.

Comment: I actually found 1 error message in the system log (EDIT 4 above)- It's a translation form the German errors message (so the wording may not be 100% accurate)

Answer (score 1):

I would start with `nltest /dsregdns` on the new DC, and remove all of the DNS records for the old DC from DNS Manager.

If the old DC is in AD Sites and Services, it should be deleted from there also.

Could be other issues. If you run `nltest /dsgetdc:<domain name>` on the new DC, it should show TIMESERV, and `net share` on the new DC should show SYSVOL and NETLOGON.

Comment: running `nltest /dsgetdc:<domain name>` on the new DC returns the error `_Getting DC name failed: Status =  1355 ox54b ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN_` (same error no matter whether I use `domain.local`or just `domain`)

Comment: the issue of not seeing the domain users listed in the >Dashboard >Users has disappeared though

Comment: On a second round going through he entries in the DNS manager of the new server I bumped over an IP addresse reference to the old SBS server in the "Forwarders" tab of `>DNS >MYDOMAIN >Propperties`. Trying to change that to the new server IP's (tried to change the existing entry and adding a new one & deleting the false entry) I get an `The servers forwarders cannot be updated. The IP address is invalid`. Removing that Forwarders entry works though. Will see whether that has any positive effect

Comment: seems removing the mention `Forwarders`entry pointing to the source SBS wasn't a good idea. Since I did that the error message even appear when the Source SBS is connected again. Adding this anew hasn't solved it neither. Also I have noticed that even though the Domain user appear in the Dashboard I've lost them in the `AD Users & Computers`. Maybe it just takes a while before the Forwarders pointer is being refreshed ?

Comment: It looks like the entries I am manually adjusting/deleting int the DNS Manager of the target server are being recreated automatically @Greg Askew.

Answer (score 0):

As we have tried different things I can't really pin the solution on a particular action.

I am pretty sure it was related to FRS vs DFSR replication method on the Source Server (SBS 2008). I'm marking the answer by @expx mentioning that as solution now, even though it was not exactly the same thing

I think the replication may finally went down the right path after we had stopped FRS and started DFSR on the Source Server. I can't really explain the detailed steps, not sequence though as it was a trial and error. Thanks everybody for the input which lead us to get this over with in the end (at least that's how it looks for now)